# How to combine the result of 2 stored procedures and combine the data to a grid view

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using SQL Server where I have 2 stored procedures:

1st stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE A
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        TC.*,       MS.*
    FROM
        VIEW1 TC,
        View2 MS
    WHERE
        TC.ID = MS.ID
    ORDER BY
        TC.Type ASC
```

2nd stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE B
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT DISTINCT
        TC.*, MS.*
    FROM
        VIEW3 TC,
        VIEW2 MS
    WHERE
        C.ID = MS.ID 
    ORDER BY 
        MS.Date DESC
```

I want to get the data result of these 2 stored procedures then bind it to a gridview. I created the following stored procedure but it throws an error that ID column is invalid:

```
CREATED PROCEDURE C
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT DISTINCT
        TC.*, MS.*
    FROM
        (VIEW1 TC
    LEFT JOIN 
        VIEW2 MS ON MS.ID = TC.ID)

    UNION 

    SELECT DISTINCT
        TC1.*, MS.*
    FROM
        (VIEW3 TC1
    LEFT JOIN
        VIEW2 MS on MS.ID = TC1.ID)
```

How can I combine the data result of 2 stored procedures? FYI, all the columns are being selected from views and not tables.

Comment: yes I'm aware of that and I checked it. and removed MySQL and tagged SQL Server

Comment: If you want to combine data sets using UNION / UNION ALL these datasets have to have the same number of columns and datatypes (which is dangerous when using select * ), after that UNION operator will force the data sort in order to remove duplicates (not sure did you plan it) so think about UNION ALL then

Answer (score 2):

In stored procedure number 3, you are using parenthesis wrong, it should be like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE C
AS    
    SELECT DISTINCT
        TC.*, MS1.*
    FROM
        VIEW1 TC
    LEFT JOIN 
        VIEW2 MS1 ON MS1.ID = TC.ID

    UNION 

    SELECT DISTINCT
        TC2.*, MS2.*
    FROM
        VIEW3 TC2
    LEFT JOIN
        VIEW2 MS2 on MS2.ID = TC2.ID
```

You can also insert the result of stored procedure into temp tables and then display the result of temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempA(Column1 NVARCHAR(50),Column2 NVARCHAR(50),...)

INSERT INTO #tempA ( Column1, Column2, ... )
 EXEC A

INSERT INTO #tempA (Column1, Column2, ...)
 EXEC B

SELECT * FROM #tempA
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to duplicate code then create a result table like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE C
AS
    CREATE TABLE #foo (bar int ...)

     INSERT INTO #foo EXEC A
     INSERT INTO #foo EXEC B

     SELECT * FROM #foo
     DROP TABLE #foo
```

or just unite queries if the columns have similar data types

```
CREATE PROCEDURE C
AS
    SELECT A.* FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            TC.*,       MS.*
        FROM
            VIEW1 TC,
            View2 MS
        WHERE
            TC.ID = MS.ID
        ORDER BY
            TC.Type ASC
    ) A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B.* FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            TC.*, MS.*
        FROM
            VIEW3 TC,
            VIEW2 MS
        WHERE
            C.ID = MS.ID 
        ORDER BY 
            MS.Date DESC
    ) B
```